# Pounds to Kilograms Conversion not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
amount = int(input("Please enter the mass in lbs you want to convert (without units): "))
if amount == int:
    return (amount / 2.2, "kilograms")
```

Python says return is outside the function? ^^^ what have i done wrong?
Would this be better?

```
def weight():
  a = int()
  a = input("What would you like to convert? ")
  if a == int:
    pounds = input("Enter a number in pounds to convert to kilos: ")
    kilos = pounds * 2.2
    print(kilos)
```

Comment: Isn't `int` a reserved word?

Comment: Is the first code block within a function? If so, can you show the whole function?

Comment: I think that what you want to check is whether the input is an integer, right? For that you can't do `a == int`, you have to write `if isinstance(a, int)`. With this the firsts code snippite should work

Comment: except if its not an int, then `int(input(xxxx))` will raise value error

Answer (score 1):

Correct design should be look like this:

```
def weight():
        pounds = input("Enter a number in pounds to convert to kilos: ")
        if pounds.isdigit():
                pounds = int(pounds)
                kilos = pounds * 2.2
                return kilos
        else:
                print("Please enter a number next time :D")

print weight()
```

Don't forget to call the function with `weight()`

Use `if pounds.isdigit():` instead of `if a == int:` or `if pounds == int:`

You have 2 minor mistakes it is very good actually.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I was trying to show him the real problem only :)

Comment: still not ... (input returns a string in python3)

Comment: @JoranBeasley I'm using Python2.7. Version is not declared in question

Comment: @JoranBeasley Please say it is fixed now :D

Comment: :D good work ... i dont know if that last sentence still holds however :P

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_int(prompt):
   ''' like input(prompt) , but guaranteed to return an integer '''
   while True:
       try:
         return int(input(prompt))
       except ValueError:
         print ("Invalid input please enter an integer!")


def weight():
    conv_type = input("What would you like to convert? ")
    if conv_type == 'pounds':
        pounds = get_int("Enter a number in pounds to convert to kilos: ")
        kilos = pounds / 2.2
        return kilos,"kg"
```

Comment: `code`conv_type = input("Enter a number in pounds to convert to kilos: ")
def weight():
    if conv_type == int:
        kilos = conv_type / 2.2
        print(kilos)`code`

is this simpler??

Comment: yes that code is simpler I guess ... but it wont work how you think it will